# What is the difference between No jutsu and Ninjutsu?

Tags: naruto

Aren't Kage Bunshin No Jutsu or Kuchiyose no jutsu of ninjutsu type?

Also please state why Kabuto told Orochimaru that Naruto isn't blessed with a technique and he relies upon the Nine Tails? He said that during Jiraiya/Tsunade fight with Orochimaru in Search for Tsunade arc. I hope Rasengan is a ninjutsu.

Comment: Can you specify a chapter or episode for that conversation between Kabuto and Orochimaru? Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, jutsu (術) means "technique", "skill", "method", "trick" or "spell".

A ninjutsu (忍術, lit. "ninja techniques") is one of the three types of jutsu that exist in Naruto. [This answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/3043/49) defines it as

> a term referring to almost any technique which allows the user to do something that they otherwise would be incapable of doing, including the usage of weapons.

As for "no jutsu" (の術): "no" (の) is a Japanese particle that, in this case, indicates possessive, and jutsu is explained above. That means that the expression "... no Jutsu" means "Technique of ..." or "... Technique".
In that way, Kage Bunshin no Jutsu (影分身の術) is translated to Shadow Clone Technique and Kuchiyose no Jutsu (口寄せの術) is translated to Summoning Technique.
And yes, these two are Ninjutsu.

Answer (score 5):

- "Jutsu" means skill or spell
- "NinJutsu" means ninja technique
- "No Jutsu" means technique of

so put that together: Kage Bunshin no Jutsu means technique of shadow clone, which is a ninja technique

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jutsu

Answer (score 3):

The first part of your question has been answered by ton yeung.

As for why Kabuto said "Naruto isn't blessed with a technique and he relies upon the Nine Tails", it's because up until then Naruto had not shown any true signs of brilliance.

He was always up to stupid acts with some sparks of brilliance that looked more like flukes than intentional actions. Even during the chunin exams, naruto had a "lucky fart" that helped him impact the battle to his favor.

Naruto is even termed as Konoha's most unpredictable knuckle head ninja.

And since most of Naruto's efforts had been mass usage of chakra (by which I mean, not effective usage of chakra) Kabuto must have said that he relies on the Nine Tails to provide him the chakra.